# Creating a list from implode data

Tags: php, implode

I currently have the following variable what would be the best way for me to create my expected result?

**Current Result:**

hi hi

**Expected Result:**

hi

hi

**Code:**

```
implode(" ", array_column($rawSubjectsArray, 'campaign_subjects'));
```

Comment: Try - `implode("\n\n", ar..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these solutions:

```
implode("\n\n", array_column($rawSubjectsArray, 'campaign_subjects'));

implode("<br/><br/>", array_column($rawSubjectsArray, 'campaign_subjects'));
```

> string implode(string $glue, array $pieces)
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Thanks was not sure about the location of it